# Header File error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I'm currently running a c++ project, with a class called Relation.

I'm trying to compile it, but I constantly get this error, regardless of the file extension that I'm using.

Compiler is cc, and the class I'm trying to compile, even when empty as below, causes this error.

I've tried the c++ header extensions, and the same errors occur.

```
#ifndef RELATION_H_
#define RELATION_H_

class Relation {
public:
Relation();
virtual ~Relation();
};

#endif
```

Comment: There's no error in this bit of code. Most probably it's in the code before you include this header (which could itself be another header)

Comment: Well, there _is_ an error if you try to run it through a C compiler rather than a C++ one, which appears to be the case :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's the error you get when you try to compile C++ code with the C compiler.

```
pax$ cat qq.cpp
class Relation {
public:
    Relation();
    virtual ~Relation();
};

pax$ g++ -c -o qq.o qq.cpp

pax$ cp qq.cpp qq.c

pax$ gcc -c -o qq.o qq.c
qq.c:4: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'Relation'
```

You should check that your `cc` compiler is actually *capable* of compiling C++ and what, if any, options are needed to make it do so.

If it's `gcc` (and it certainly *looks* like it is, based on the absolutely identical error message), you may need to make sure that you're calling `g++` rather than `gcc` and/or that your extension for the source file (not header) is a recognised one, like `.cpp` <sup>(a)</sup>.

I'm not *entirely* certain the rules that `gcc` follows but I've always found it safer to use source files like `blahblah.cpp` and *explicitly* use `g++`.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Reasoning: since you mention in your particular case that you're using the correct *header* file extensions, I think one possibility is that the header extension has no effect whatsoever on what `gcc` tries to compile the source file as. It uses only the *source* file extension, as per the following transcript:

```
pax$ cat xyzzy.hpp
class Relation {
public:
    Relation();
    virtual ~Relation();
};

pax$ cat plugh.c
#include "xyzzy.hpp"

pax$ gcc -c -o plugh.o plugh.c
In file included from plugh.c:1:
xyzzy.hpp:1: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__'
                    before 'Relation'

pax$ cp plugh.c plugh.cpp

pax$ gcc -c -o plugh.o plugh.cpp
```

In other words, I don't think having an included header file of (for example) `xyzzy.hpp` would force the compiler to compile C++ if the source file that's including it is still `plugh.c`.

Comment: I had added an existing *.c file for test purposes, everything was fine until I tried to include a *.h file with class definitions. Scratching my head because every time i commented out the header it worked. Changed the *.c to *.cpp and boom, works like a charm. Sometimes its right in front of your face and it just takes a little nudge from an answer like this. Thanks again.